# NSNotification not returning

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotifications

I have a modal`UIViewController` that has a `UITableView` on it. For whatever cell the user selects, I want to return that text to the previous view controller and dismiss the modal view. I'm using NSNotifications to send the value back. Problem is, my notification is never received.

Here is the code from the 'parent' view:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(choiceReceived:)
                                                 name:@"selectionMade"
                                               object:nil];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"locationsDetailsSegue" sender: self];
}

- (void) choiceReceived: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"test");

    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
    NSString *user_choice = [dict objectForKey:@"choice"];

    NSLog(@"%@", user_choice);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name: @"selectionMade"
                                                  object:nil];
}
```

And in the modal view controller:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *choice = cell.textLabel.text;

    // send a notification of this choice back to the 'parent' controller
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:choice forKey:@"choice"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"selectionMade" object:nil userInfo:dict];

    NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"choice"]);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I get the correct output from the notifier, but I get no output whatsoever from the receiver. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Comment: Is the original VC definitely still alive when the notification is posted?

Comment: Is the parent view implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` always called before the modal view controller's implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is? These are different tableViews, right?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I'm not 100% sure. The original VC calls this VC modally, so I believe it is still there, but I don't know how to verify that. I've use this pattern in other situations, and it's always worked, so I don't know why it fails here. I think I'll look into the delegate pattern, since I need to learn that anyway.

Comment: @ThomasW - There is a button on the parent VC that launches the segue to the modal VC. But this button and it's IBAction are outside of the parent's didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Should that make a difference?

Comment: The Allocations Instrument will help you figure that out if you need to, but not using notifications for this is a better solution anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, i don't like use `NSNotificationCenter` in such scenario (*Its just my suggestion*).  I'm always recommend delegate pattern in such case. Delegation pattern working or communicate one-to-one object notification so it give 100% precise output and removing other conflicts.
Create protocol methods in childviewcontroller and delegate property for confirmation in parentclassviewcontroller.
Consume chileviewcontroller protocol in parentviewcontroller. Implement required delegate methods of protocol in parentviewcontroller class. Also you can send multiple types of arguments through delegates method.
for more info go through this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html).

Comment: Thanks. I took some time and got up to speed on the delegate pattern. Much more reliable.